# How do you write a simple unit test case to handle http404 without accessing the server using any OOP language?

Tags: api, http, exception, http-status-code-404

Assume the application consumes a third-party HTTP API.

Answer (score 0):

You likely have a client library that lets you interact with http services. You need to prepare a special sort of object (again if your "any" language is object oriented) ([mock object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object)) that would be treated by your code under test as the regualar object.

The only differece is that for your test the method that is responsible for endpoint invocation would always return 404 error.

Comment: thank you for your reply, but how would you write a unit test (using any OOP language) to handle http404 error? Sorry, I am not familiar with writing unit test.